# R: I entered numbers into the data frame but is showing it to me as character

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following code which should show the pm25, fips, longitude and latitude as numeric so I can do five number summaries but instead is showing it as a character. I don't understand why.  I can convert each column to numeric but that is too inefficient when dealing with a lot of data tables.

Again question is why is pm25, fips, longitude, and latitude showing as character?

```
x <- data.frame(9, 01003, "east", -87.75, 30.59)
colnames(x) <- c("pm25", "fips", "region", "longitude", "latitude")
x
x <- rbind(x, c(9, 01027, "east", -85.84, 33.27))
x <- rbind(x, c(10, 01033, "east", -87.73, 34.73))
x <- rbind(x, c(11, 01049, "east", -85.80, 34.46))
x <- rbind(x, c(12, 01055, "east", -86.03, 34.02))
x <- rbind(x, c(10, 01069, "east", -85.35, 31.19))
x

#Five-number summary
summary(x$pm25)
summary(x$fips)
summary(x$longitude)
summary(x$latitude)
```

RESULT:

```
> x <- data.frame(9, 01003, "east", -87.75, 30.59)
> colnames(x) <- c("pm25", "fips", "region", "longitude", "latitude")
> x
  pm25 fips region longitude latitude
1    9 1003   east    -87.75    30.59
> x <- rbind(x, c(9, 01027, "east", -85.84, 33.27))
> x <- rbind(x, c(10, 01033, "east", -87.73, 34.73))
> x <- rbind(x, c(11, 01049, "east", -85.80, 34.46))
> x <- rbind(x, c(12, 01055, "east", -86.03, 34.02))
> x <- rbind(x, c(10, 01069, "east", -85.35, 31.19))
> x
  pm25 fips region longitude latitude
1    9 1003   east    -87.75    30.59
2    9 1027   east    -85.84    33.27
3   10 1033   east    -87.73    34.73
4   11 1049   east     -85.8    34.46
5   12 1055   east    -86.03    34.02
6   10 1069   east    -85.35    31.19
> 
> #Five-number summary
> summary(x$pm25)
   Length     Class      Mode 
        6 character character 
> summary(x$fips)
   Length     Class      Mode 
        6 character character 
> summary(x$longitude)
   Length     Class      Mode 
        6 character character 
> summary(x$latitude)
   Length     Class      Mode 
        6 character character
```

Comment: `c(9, 01027, "east", -85.84, 33.27)` produces a character vector.  You need `list()` instead of `c()` there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer from the comments on my question by Rich Scriven.
Since he hasn't answered it here and for the purpose of closing the question I am going to give credit to myself.  If he answers it here I will give him credit.
Give him credit/up vote if you can.

`c(9, 01027, "east", -85.84, 33.27)` produces a character vector. You need `list()` instead of `c()` there.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call summary as

```
summary(as.numeric(x$fips))
```

So you code will be like

```
x <- data.frame(9, 01003, "east", -87.75, 30.59)
colnames(x) <- c("pm25", "fips", "region", "longitude", "latitude")
x <- rbind(x, c(9, 01027, "east", -85.84, 33.27))
x <- rbind(x, c(10, 01033, "east", -87.73, 34.73))
x <- rbind(x, c(11, 01049, "east", -85.80, 34.46))
x <- rbind(x, c(12, 01055, "east", -86.03, 34.02))
x <- rbind(x, c(10, 01069, "east", -85.35, 31.19))\
summary(as.numeric(x$fips))

# summary(as.numeric(x$fips))
# Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
# 1003    1028    1041    1039    1054    1069
```